# What is the set of subdifferentials of $f$ at $x = -1$ for $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 2x^2 + x +2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, subgradient

> What is the set of subdifferentials of $f$ at  $x = -1$ for
> $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = 2x^2 + x +2$

I am taking online classes and my instructor has given this definition of set of subdifferentials :

Set of subdifferentials of $f$ at $x_0$ are vectors $g$ such that

$$f(x) \geq f(x_0) + g^T (x-x_0)$$

But how do I use this to get the set of subdifferentials? Sorry I can't show my attempt because I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for all $g\in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R$ we have
$$
2x^2+x+2 \ge 3 + g\, (x+1).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
g\,(x+1) \le 2x^2+x-1.
$$

Note that $2x^2+x-1 = (x+1)(2x-1)$.

When $x=-1$, the inequality is satisfied for any $g$.

When $x<-1$, dividing by $(x+1)$ flips the inequality and we get
$$
g \ge (2x-1) \quad\text{for all $x<-1$},
$$
which yields $g\ge -3$.

When $x>-1$, dividing by $(x+1)$ does not flip the inequality and we get
$$
g \le (2x-1) \quad\text{for all $x>-1$},
$$
which yields $g\le -3$.

Hence $g=-3$ is the only subdifferential of $f$ at $x_0=-1$ and the set of subdifferentials is $\{-3\}$.

Comment: thank you very much